# Simple SQL Problem

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL query that I cant wrap my mind around. I do not have a large amount of sql experience. So I need some help

I have a table XXX:

```
Social Security No (SSN).
Name.
organisation. (Finance/IT)
```

In english what I want is:

**To select all SSNs and Names in "Finance" where there is a different name for that SSN in "IT".**

My not working attempt:

**select ssn , name from XXX where org = "Finance" and name not in (select name from XXX where org="IT" and ssn=the_first_ssn)**

Please help.

---

I have decided to make it a bit more difficult.

SSN can ocur multiple times in "IT":

**So I want to select all SSNs and Names in Finance where the SSN does not exist with the same Name in "IT"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery in an `exists` clause:

```
select  ssn, name
from    YourTable a
where   organisation = 'Finance'
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable b
        where   organisation = 'IT'
                and a.ssn = b.ssn
                and a.name <> b.name
        )
```

The subquery says there must be a row in IT with the same SSN but a different name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. It looks like i needed to store the table as "a", then I can rweference the sriginal querys data.
Perfect.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ssn is a unique key...

```
select ssn, name 
from XXX XXX1
where org = "Finance" 
and ssn in 
(
select ssn 
from XXX XXX2
where org="IT"
and XXX1.name<>XXX2.name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct
t1.ssn,
t1.name
from
xxx t1
inner join xxx t2 on t1.ssn=t2.ssn and t1.name<>t2.name
where t1.org='Finance' and t2.org='IT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'm working on learning SQL and I wanted to try my hand at a solution and compare against the existing answers. I created a table `Personnel` with some testing data.

1. My SQL Server only query uses CTEs and an `INNER JOIN`:

   ```
    WITH
        Finance AS (SELECT SSN, Name FROM Personnel WHERE Org = 'Finance'),
        IT AS (SELECT SSN, Name FROM Personnel WHERE Org = 'IT')
    SELECT Finance.SSN, Finance.Name
        FROM Finance
        INNER JOIN IT ON IT.SSN = Finance.SSN
        WHERE IT.Name != Finance.Name
   ```
2. [Alexander's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423028/simple-sql-problem/3423112#3423112) uses a straight `INNER JOIN`. I rewrote it a little bit, putting the name comparison in the `WHERE` clause, and dropping `DISTINCT` because it's not required:

   ```
    SELECT Finance.SSN, Finance.Name
        FROM Personnel Finance
        INNER JOIN Personnel IT ON Finance.SSN = IT.SSN
        WHERE
            (Finance.Org = 'Finance' AND IT.Org = 'IT') AND
            (Finance.Name != IT.Name)
   ```
3. [Andomar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423028/simple-sql-problem/3423074#3423074) using a correlated subquery inside an `EXISTS` clause:

   ```
    SELECT SSN, Name
        FROM Personnel a
        WHERE
            (Org = 'Finance') AND
            EXISTS
            (
                SELECT *
                    FROM Personnel b
                    WHERE (Org = 'IT') AND (a.SSN = b.SSN) AND (a.Name != b.Name)
            )
   ```
4. [barrylloyd's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423028/simple-sql-problem/3423079#3423079) using a correlated subquery inside an `IN` clause:

   ```
    SELECT SSN, Name
        FROM Personnel p1
        WHERE
            (Org = 'Finance') AND
            SSN IN
            (
                SELECT SSN FROM Personnel p2
                    WHERE (Org = 'IT') AND (p1.Name != p2.Name)
            )
   ```

I plugged all of these into SQL Server, and it turns out that queries 1 and 2 both generate the same query plan, and queries 3 and 4 generate the same query plan. The difference between the two groups is the former group actually does an `INNER JOIN` internally, while the latter group does a left semi-join instead. ([See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/introduction-to-joins) for an explanation of the different types of joins.)

I'm assuming there is a *slight* performance advantage favouring the left semi-join; however, for the business case, if you want to see any data columns from the right table (for example, if you want to display *both* names to compare them), you would have to completely rewrite those queries to use an `INNER JOIN`-based solution.

So given all that, I would favour solution 2, because the performance is so similar to 3 and 4, and it's far more flexible than those as well. My solution makes the `SELECT` statement very easy to read, but it's more verbose than 2 and not as portable. I suppose that mine might be better for readability if you have to do additional filtering on each of the two "sub-tables," or if the results of this query are going to be used as an intermediate step to a further goal.